# cocos2dx crash on android during release of unknown objects, working fine on IOS

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using `cocos2dx-3.3` with `ndk-r10d` on `eclipse` and my testing device is samsung galaxy S3.
There is a object of Class derived from `CClayer` added to the `CCScene` object. The game is crashing when a new layer is added and old layer is removing from the scene. The layer has `TMXLayer` object as child on which other `Node` objects are added like `TTFLabel`, `Node` etc.

The error in eclipse logs is as below:

```
11-20 14:25:56.964: A/libc(23300): @@@ ABORTING: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x6fa7dce8 passed to dlfree

11-20 14:25:56.964: A/libc(23300): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 23319 (Thread-5050)
```

The probable error is when some node is clearing its children vector and the vector is releasing its elements.

The ndk crash dump shows this:

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/m0xx/m0:4.3/JSS15J/I9300XXUGND3:user/release-keys'
pid: 6306, tid: 6344, name: Thread-553  >>> com.playbuff.BOWFinal <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
Stack frame #00  pc 0001e824  /system/lib/libc.so
Stack frame #01  pc 0001c76c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
Stack frame #02  pc 000122ed  /system/lib/libc.so
Stack frame #03  pc 00010f9d  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1184)
Stack frame #04  pc 0000dabf  /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
Stack frame #05  pc 00782c4b  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (operator delete(void*)+8): Routine operator delete(void*) at /tmp/ndk-user/tmp/build-libc++/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/../llvm-libc++abi/libcxxabi/src/cxa_new_delete.cpp:144
Stack frame #06  pc 00456e47  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Sprite::~Sprite()+10): Routine cocos2d::Sprite::~Sprite() at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCSprite.cpp:296 (discriminator 2)
Stack frame #07  pc 00478997  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Ref::release()+30): Routine cocos2d::Ref::release() at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCRef.cpp:146 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame #08  pc 00316cbd  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Node*>::clear()+14): Routine cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Node*>::clear() at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCVector.h:396 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame #09  pc 0044abfd  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Node::~Node()+244): Routine _ZN7cocos2d6VectorIPNS_4NodeEED4Ev at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCVector.h:88
Stack frame #10  pc 004585c5  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::SpriteBatchNode::~SpriteBatchNode()+84): Routine cocos2d::SpriteBatchNode::~SpriteBatchNode() at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCSpriteBatchNode.cpp:119 (discriminator 3)
Stack frame #11  pc 004585e9  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::SpriteBatchNode::~SpriteBatchNode()+4): Routine cocos2d::SpriteBatchNode::~SpriteBatchNode() at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCSpriteBatchNode.cpp:122
Stack frame #12  pc 00478997  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Ref::release()+30): Routine cocos2d::Ref::release() at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCRef.cpp:146 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame #13  pc 00316cbd  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Node*>::clear()+14): Routine cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Node*>::clear() at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCVector.h:396 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame #14  pc 0044abfd  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Node::~Node()+244): Routine _ZN7cocos2d6VectorIPNS_4NodeEED4Ev at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCVector.h:88
Stack frame #15  pc 00456e17  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Sprite::~Sprite()+170): Routine cocos2d::Sprite::~Sprite() at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCSprite.cpp:286 (discriminator 7)
Stack frame #16  pc 00456e41  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Sprite::~Sprite()+4): Routine cocos2d::Sprite::~Sprite() at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCSprite.cpp:296
Stack frame #17  pc 00478997  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Ref::release()+30): Routine cocos2d::Ref::release() at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCRef.cpp:146 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame #18  pc 00316cbd  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Node*>::clear()+14): Routine cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Node*>::clear() at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCVector.h:396 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame #19  pc 0044abfd  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Node::~Node()+244): Routine _ZN7cocos2d6VectorIPNS_4NodeEED4Ev at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCVector.h:88
Stack frame #20  pc 0045c197  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::TMXTiledMap::~TMXTiledMap()+130): Routine cocos2d::TMXTiledMap::~TMXTiledMap() at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCTMXTiledMap.cpp:97 (discriminator 3)
Stack frame #21  pc 00390303  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (TileMap::~TileMap()+26): Routine TileMap::~TileMap() at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../Classes/model/TileMap.cpp:25 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame #22  pc 00390315  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (TileMap::~TileMap()+4): Routine TileMap::~TileMap() at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../Classes/model/TileMap.cpp:30
Stack frame #23  pc 00478997  /data/app-lib/com.playbuff.BOWFinal-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Ref::release()+30): Routine cocos2d::Ref::release() at /Users/PB037/Desktop/DKT/BOW-3.3-May11/BOWFinal/proj.android/jni/../../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCRef.cpp:146 (discriminator 1)
```

The problem is this crash is not happening on `IOS` devices and I couldn't find the `Node` object which is causing this crash. Please tell me a method to find the defective `Node`. Thanks.
PS: I've tried with the `ndk-r9d` also.

Comment: I am getting the sam problem.